# What’s なく after a verb for?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Given the following text:

> 東京都のある女性が、2017年10月23日から連絡が取れ[なく]{LL}なり、[行方]{«ゆくえ»}[不明]{ふ・めい}になっていた。

What’s the grammar for 「なく」after「取れ」? (e.g passive form or negate form, for further googling)

Also, would that be different if I use 「連絡が取れない」?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you (probably) know, ～なる means "to become".  For ナ-adjectives and nouns, it is preceded by に, such as 友達になる, 元気になる, etc.  For イ-adjectives and words that conjugate like them, it is preceded by the "adverbial" ～く form; 新しくなる, 明るくなる, 行きたくなる ("become wanting to go"), etc.

This is just a case of the ～ない form of the verbー取れない (which conjugates like an イ-adj.)ーbehaving "adverbially" in front of なる.  So it would translate as, "A Tokyo woman became un**able** (取れる is the potential form) to be reached after 2017/10/23, and her whereabouts were unknown".

> Also, would that be different if I use 「連絡が取れない」?

You could not just use 取れない here because of the から in the sentence.  It's saying that *starting* on that date, contact with her could not be made, and continued on for some time.  If it were に instead of から, then you could use 取れない because then it's just a one-time action.

Comment: The explanation is amazing! Thanks!